# Highcharts PieChart Legend paging faulty

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, pie-chart

Creating a few pie charts using Highcharts which render fine, however the legend does not swap between pages. It updates the page number (E.g. 1/4 -> 2/4 -> 3/4) but the contents of the legend does not change.

I have used code from http://jsfiddle.net/qegmnsm7/ and simply passed my own data into it; giving this code:

```
var areaOptions = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'areaPie',
        defaultSeriesType: 'pie',
        width: 900,
        height: 600
    },
    title: {
        text: "Test Pie Chart."
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 30,
        navigation: {
            activeColor: '#3E576F',
            animation: true,
            arrowSize: 12,
            inactiveColor: '#CCC',
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: '#333',
                fontSize: '12px'    
            }
        }
    },
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            printButton: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#000000',
                connectorColor: '#000000',
                formatter: function () {
                    return Math.round(this.percentage) + '% (' + this.y + ')';
                }
            },
            showInLegend: true
                , point: {
                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: function () {
                            filterList(this);
                            this.select();
                            return false;
                        },
                        click: function () { filterList(this); }
                    }
                }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Banana',
            data: []
        }]
    }
};
areaOptions.series = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Area);
var areaChart = new Highcharts.Chart(areaOptions);
areaChart.render();
```

Giving this:
[image]

However upon clicking the 'down' arrow, the legend stays exactly the same - apart from 1/2 changes to 2/2.

I have used the example code linked above in my application and it works perfectly; therefore I expected simply updating the data input to work. However something is messing it up and I can't find any other users' questions or google links to help.

What am I doing wrong that stops the legend from paging properly?

Edit: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kfdoxscx/8/) is a JSFiddle showing exactly what I mean.

Comment: Could you recreate your problem in a JSFiddle? The one that you posted is working fine and I am unable to recreate the problem. Do you have errors in browser console (Developer Tools) ?

Comment: On another note entirely, if you have a pie chart with so many slices that the legend needs to paginate (given the inherent failure of even a well constructed pie chart), what value do you expect a user can *possibly* get from such a chart?

Comment: @jlbriggs This is a request from my manager - I'm just providing what he's asked for :)

Comment: @KacperMadej I'll do that now.

Comment: @KacperMadej Forgot to say that there are no errors in developer tools.

Comment: @KacperMadej Here is the jFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kfdoxscx/8/

Comment: @Craig What for are you using the last line of JS? Without it scrolling works and it doesn't look like mentioned code is needed - https://jsfiddle.net/kfdoxscx/9/

Comment: @KacperMadej Ah wow, thank you. A colleague of mine had that line on his usage of it; therefore I assumed it was required. Thank you for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`areaChart.render();` is not a part of official API and is causing the problem with legend paging. Removing this part of code will fix you issue.

Fixed code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kfdoxscx/9/